# drawing polyline, markers for many places at once

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have a project on Google map based application. it is similar to Maps application provided by Google. i selected this project because Google do not provide enough information, route and other facilities that are available for other countries.

So my project objective is

1. current location
2. shortest path with path highlighted
3. showing places
4. information about places.

These are the main objective and I have obtained map and current location. So I need help on other objective.

And as I learned many thing  by searching and from other source. shortest path is mathematical. polyline is available in Google map for highlight and I referred
[How to draw road directions between two geocodes in android google map v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710744/how-to-draw-road-directions-between-two-geocodes-in-android-google-map-v2) 
but was not helpful for me. I am using `sq-lite` for database.

You may think this is as not specific question and this is my first question and trying to fit in stackoverflow pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much Kirk for editing.

Comment: i do not want to create new one so i m asking here. how to obtain browser key for google place api