# draw road between two locations in google map v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm trying to draw a road/path between two location that i provide my code is currently looking like this :

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

LatLng lt = new LatLng(35.7687310, -5.8280540);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lt).title("Home"));
LatLng lt2 = new LatLng(35.7462510, -5.8481330);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lt2).title("School"));
```

i need to draw a road direction between the two markers , thanks
i've searched for solutions but most of them are old & can't run them as they crash ...
i hope you could help  , thanks

**EDIT :** 
my main problem was that i was trying to use my api on another project that doesn't contain the same package name , thanks for your help guys ;)

Comment: **Look at this reference if its helpfull:-** 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710744/how-to-draw-road-directions-between-two-geocodes-in-android-google-map-v2
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2

Comment: Where is it crashed?

Comment: it crashes when i start the app

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one:


        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map_rideshare)).getMap();

            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


            v2GetRouteDirection = new GMapV2GetRouteDirection();


            String url = getDirectionsUrl(new LatLng(source_lat,source_long), new LatLng(destination_lat,destination_long));
            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

            // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
            downloadTask.execute(url);

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(Ride_Share.this,
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }



        private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }


    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";

            if(result.size()<1){
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                        continue;
                    }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                        duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(4);
                lineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
            }

            //tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }
```

Add this class

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class GMapV2GetRouteDirection {

    public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

    public GMapV2GetRouteDirection() { }

    public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
        Log.i("GMAP", "step2");
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude 
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

        Log.i("url", url);
        Log.i("GMAP", "step3");
        try {
            Log.i("GMAP", "step4");
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.i("GMAP", "step5");
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            Log.i("GMAP", "step6");
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            Log.i("GMAP", "step7");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            Log.i("GMAP", "step8");
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            Log.i("GMAP", "step9");
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Log.i("GMAP", "step10");
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            Log.i("GMAP", "step11");

            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
            if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if u face any problem

Comment: Please add your own implemented code. Don't just copy paste code http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-draw-route-between-two-geo.html

Comment: @PiyushGupta ..Whats the problem with these code...Above code works fine in my application..

Comment: If it is then you just need to share links not do a copy paste a code. What is the meaning for that. Only to earn a reputation?

Comment: @PiyushGupta I just want to help these person...And there is no any other intention behind it..Today i have created the account in these site and you have to motivate me or need to edit in my post instead of point out the error..I did not copy and paste from yours given link...As i was working in the same project therefore i have copied it from my application and than paste it here...

Comment: I am motivating you with this

Comment: OK thanks for yours motivation..But i am literally saying to you that I have not copied these code from yours link...Or any other link..

Comment: Ok. Great Than. Best of luck !

Comment: i'm tring my best to figure out a way to work with this code , so i've created a class called GMapV2GetRouteDirection and a pasted that class to it , working great without any problem , then i went to my main activity , i pasted the first part of the code (until the toast and the next 2 closing } into oncreate) , then i pasted the rest methode outside of oncreate , now i'm getting an error saying that   DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser(); cannot be resolved into a type (there is no class on that name i guess) , could you please help ? thanks