# Is there a way to draw itinerary between two GPS positions using Google Map API on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am trying to add a feature to my app allowing users to prepare their itinerary for a road trip.
So what I'd like to do is to be able to draw a car itinerary between two locations and display it in a static way on a map.
I'd like to be able to get information like distance, duration of trip, traffic, and all relevant information for a road trip.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: not that much information is possible to retrieve.  though, you can use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710744/how-to-draw-road-directions-between-two-geocodes-in-android-google-map-v2  to draw polylines from two points. but many of the information you require , can't be accessed via your app. google discourages since maps api V2 to use google service maps as GPRS navigators.

Comment: you could also configure the map to show traffic too, bot not distance, time left, etc... you should be "calculating" all that data by yourself measuring distance between the polyline vertex and the user location and redrawing them as he moves.