# Displaying Routes between multiple markers in Google Maps API Android

Tags: api, routes, maps, markers

any idea how I can display the route paths between multiple markers in Google Maps API for Android ?

Currently I have several markers and i would like to display the routes between a set of markers. How do I do that ?

Comment: I guess no one knows how to do this, or no one wants to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw routes path based on my own markers in android Google maps v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456589/draw-routes-path-based-on-my-own-markers-in-android-google-maps-v2)