# Android studio google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying with Google maps in android studio, I want to find alternative paths from source to destination, how do I implement this part? It is showing a single route between source and destination currently

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) Please look at How to [Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will help to get useful answers

Comment: Possible to duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14710744/2078074

Answer (score 0):

## Direction API

Direction Request without Alternate Route

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Nevada,%20USA&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&key=API_KEY
```

Fastest route will be given.

Result:

1. Route 1

   - Distance: 489 mi
   - Duration: 9 hours 29 mins

Direction Request with Alternate Route

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Nevada,%20USA&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&alternatives=true&key=API_KEY
```

Each route will be under "[legs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Legs)".

> Each element in the legs array specifies a single leg of the journey from the origin to the destination in the calculated route. For routes that contain no waypoints, the route will consist of a single "leg," but for routes that define one or more waypoints, the route will consist of one or more legs, corresponding to the specific legs of the journey.

Result:

1. Route 1

   - Distance: 489 mi
   - Duration: 9 hours 29 mins
2. Route 2

   - Distance: 475 mi
   - Duration: 9 hours 36 mins
3. Route 3

   - Distance: 511 mi
   - Duration: 9 hours 39 mins

Here is a screenshot of the google maps with the same request.

[image]

Note: The duration may not be the same for the web Google Maps and Direction API. There will still be about few minutes of difference. API key must be a **SERVER KEY**.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.akexorcist.com/2015/12/google-direction-library-for-android-en.html) for implementation.

Hope this helps!